# Missing location of warnings and occurrences in Spyder 4

Tags: python, spyder

I upgraded this morning to Spyder 4.1, on my laptop with OS X 10.13. I am not sure if it's a problem of the Mac release of Spyder, or of this version (I hadn't used Spyder on my laptop in a while), but it seems that the space in the editor where warnings or occurrences are listed is gone.

There used to be in the editor a scroll bar next to the standard one, on the right, that was highlighting the portion of code that was being displayed, and then the position of warnings, errors and occurrences, like this one on the right:

[image]

But this is now gone - at least for me, on OS X, as you can see here:
[image]

I checked, and "basic linting" is enabled in Preferences, and I have tried un-ticking it and ticking it again, without success. Is this a problem of the OS X release, do I have to enable another option, or is it simply gone from the new version?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There are no errors/warnings in the section of the file your screenshot is showing above. But there's one some lines above, signaled by the orange line to the right. So if you there, you'll see a warning to the right.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba that's a screenshot of the previous release of Spyder, where indeed you could see the orange light, and the darker ones for the position of the variable that is highlighted in the text. It's precisely that section with the lines that I cannot find in Spyder 4. Sorry, maybe I was not clear!

Comment: Ok, sorry. So could you update your question with a Spyder 4 screenshot?

Comment: Done! As you can see, you see on the right there is no lines showing where the variable "echoes" appears in the code, and there is no orange line for the warning. Does this have something to do with the linting options?

Comment: Ok, I see. There was a bug reported about this and the user said that it was solved by closing Spyder, running `spyder --reset` in a terminal (the Anaconda Prompt in your case) and starting Spyder again.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. Unfortunately I tried on my Mac, running directly from the terminal `spyder --reset`, and while it did reset files to the standard settings, the additional bar didn't appear on Spyder, now also updated to 4.1.1, and after several restarts of Spyder and Anaconda. Basic Linting is still enabled. As a sanity checked I updated Spyder on Windows, and there it works fine.

Comment: What's your macOS version?

Comment: In the end I tried restarting the laptop as well, and now it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Great news! I'm going to add an answer below so other people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To fix this problem you need to open a terminal (cmd.exe, Terminal.app or xterm) and run there:

`spyder --reset`

If that's not enough, you also need to restart your computer.

Comment: Unfortunately the problems seems to be resurfacing periodically! I can't figure out what it is due to...